# Why would an UPDATE SET REPLACE() statement match rows, but change none and give no warnings?

Tags: mysql, dml

I'm seeking a certain string in a field and want to replace it with a new string. Specifically, I want all references to one URL to be changed to another URL. I've crafted this SQL statement and am running it at a `mysql>` prompt on CentOS 5.5 using MySQL Community Server 5.1.54.

```
update [table] set [field] = REPLACE([field],'%domain.com%','%domain.org%');
```

The response is:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Rows matched: 618  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

How can I track down why no changes are being made?

### EDIT 1:

Thanks to Aaron Bertrand, I discovered that `REPLACE()` cannot handle wildcards and I was using it completely wrong (think: missing `WHERE` clause). Here's is my reformed statement:

```
UPDATE [table]
SET [column] =
REPLACE (
    [column],
    'companydomain.com',
    'companydomain.org' )
WHERE
    [column]
LIKE
    '%companydomain.com%';
```

To which I receive the old, familiar:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Rows matched: 167  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

What could I be doing wrong?

### EDIT 2:

***I'll tell you what I was doing wrong!!*** I was not questioning assumptions. My *assumption* was that the string that I was replacing was in all lower case. The WHERE clause was returning all things that looked `LIKE %companydomain.com%`. That includes all capitalization permutations such as CompanyDomain.com, CoMpAnYdOmAiN.com and etc.

It passed that on to `REPLACE()` which then was looking strictly for companydomain.com to then replace it with companydomain.org.

```
REPLACE (
    [column],
    'companydomain.com',
    'companydomain.org' )
```

So of course my records were being returned, but nothing was being replaced. Once I changed `REPLACE()` to take the capitalization into account, all records were updated and it appears that all is well. The correct `REPLACE()` syntax for my scenario was thus:

```
REPLACE (
    [column],
    'CompanyDomain.com',
    'companydomain.org' )
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`REPLACE` does not play with wildcards that way. I think you meant:

```
UPDATE [table] 
  SET [column] = REPLACE([column],'TLD.com','TLD.org')
  WHERE [column] LIKE '%TLD.com%';
```

You have no `WHERE` clause, so it *tried* to update 618 rows, but it did not find any instances of `%TLD.com%` in that column. To see which rows should be affected, run a `SELECT` instead:

```
SELECT [column], REPLACE([column], 'TLD.com', 'TLD.org') AS new_value
  FROM [table]
  WHERE [column] LIKE '%TLD.com%';
```

Answer (score 0):

First, we have to check using a `select` query:

```
SELECT * FROM colleges
WHERE course_name LIKE '%&amp%'
```

Next, we have to update:

```
UPDATE colleges
SET course_name = REPLACE(course_name, '&amp', '&')
WHERE id = 1
```

Results: `Cloud &amp Enterprise Computing` ⇒ `Cloud & Enterprise Computing`

Finally, we have to apply for all:

```
UPDATE colleges
SET course_name = REPLACE(course_name, '&amp', '&')
```

Results: `Corporate &amp Insolvency Law` ⇒ `Corporate & Insolvency Law`